# 3D manifestation of a higher dimensional object

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, branes, visualization

The starting points of this theorical exploration are the following.
I do believe we exist in a universe where 10 (or 11) dimensions do exist, but the ones beyond 3 spatial + 1 time are compactified.

I am not interested in answers refuting this, not as a sign of arrogance but just because they would miss the point of my question, which is to craft an hypothesys about how this could work if being real.

Now, let's imagine a 4 dimensional spatial object was to interact with our universe.
Since we have not extended/large extra dimensions, would it be possible for such an object to interact with our universe, or would it be totally prevented from contact? Would the particles that compose it be forced to assume a different set of physical laws as they are being forced to self-limit to 3d? Would it dilate compactified extra dimensions locally to carve out a niche for itself, retaining its original 4d properties? Would it exist as a gas composed of planck-lenght mini-universes which are the manifestation, in our universe, of extra dimensions? No need to answer or refute the aforementioned list point by point, it's not pivotal to me, what I am looking for is, a 4 dimensional object, coming from a universe where 4 spatial large/extended dimensions do exist, would (it does not matter how nor why) collide with our universe. Would it be pushed back because we do not have enough dimensions to allow for its full manifestation? Or manifest as a 3 dimensional "avatar" of itself? in this case, would the particles it was originally made of, keep their properties, and stir physical laws from its original universe, or will it be forced to work under our laws?
To make an OBSCENELY lewd (from a scientific point of view) example, some theories propose that in more than 5 dimensions gravity could be deflected or even repelled. I am not here interested in debating this but, upon it being possible, was a 5 dimensional object to enter our universe, would it levitate? I mean, in this hypothesys, it was able to levitate in its universe because (in this hypothesys) in a universe with 5 large spatial dimensions gravitons behave like photons and they can be manipulated just like we can manipulate heat... would such object carry this property when manifesting in our universe? Or would it be forced to manifest as a 3 dimensional object and thus subject to gravity?

For whoever was trying to reply, please AVOID the example of flatlandia and the balloon intersecting their 2-d sight capabiliity: in that example there is a 3 dimensional large spatial dimension which allows for the balloon to exist in their same universe and interact with flatlandia, while we have NO fourth large spatial dimension so we have NO ROOM for a four dimensional object simply occupying space in a fourth spatial dimension imperceptible to us but next to us.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> The starting points of this theorical exploration are the following. I do believe we exist in a universe where 10 (or 11) dimensions do exist, but the ones beyond 3 spatial + 1 time are compactified.

> Now, let's imagine a 4 dimensional object was to interact with our universe. Since we have not extended/large extra dimensions, would it be possible for such an object to interact with our universe, or would it be totally prevented from contact?

Between these two statements, we can confidently say that whatever happens in such an imaginary scenario must necessarily exist outside of the physics described with the 10(or 11) dimensions with all but 3+1 compactified.  What happens in this scenario is completely defined by a physics unknown to you and I.  Quite literally what happens is undefined by any physics that you and I recognize, unless we recognize a particular physics which includes 4 non-compactified dimensions.  The question indicates that no such physics is recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains a contradiction.

There are no 3D or 4D objects. All objects are 9D (nine spatial dimensions and one time dimension) but 6 of the spatial dimensions are compact. You seem to be asking if an object with 3 large and 6 compact dimensions could interact with an object with 4 large and 5 compact dimensions, but this cannot happen.

The number of compact dimensions is a property of the spacetime, not of the objects in that spacetime. That means *all* objects must have the same number of extended and compact dimensions, so the interaction you describe cannot occur by definition. Objects with 3 and 4 extended dimensions cannot exist in the same universe.